GCP GKE DNS Networking is being flaky
We have a GKE K8s cluster deployed in GCP and the pods are having trouble resolving DNS.
It looks like it may be flaky networking, but I am not understanding what is going on.
If I run nslookup inside the pod it sometimes work and sometimes I get a connection error.
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1

If I look at the resolv.conf I see that the nameserver is set to go to the k8s-dns service.
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <podf> -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
search <namespace>.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local us-east4-a.c.<project id>.internal c.<project id>.internal google.internal
nameserver 10.128.0.10
options ndots:5

If I try to ping the DNS server it doesn't work:
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- ping 10.128.0.10
PING 10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.128.0.10 ping statistics ---
33 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
command terminated with exit code 1

If I use netcat to explore opening a connection it shows that opening a connection is very flaky:
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nc -v -z -w 3  10.128.0.10 53
nc: 10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10:53): Operation timed out
command terminated with exit code 1
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nc -v -z -w 3  10.128.0.10 53
10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10:53) open
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nc -v -z -w 3  10.128.0.10 53
10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10:53) open
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nc -v -z -w 3  10.128.0.10 53
10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10:53) open
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nc -v -z -w 3  10.128.0.10 53
10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10:53) open
% kubectl exec -n <namespace> -ti <pod> -- nc -v -z -w 3  10.128.0.10 53
nc: 10.128.0.10 (10.128.0.10:53): Operation timed out
command terminated with exit code 1

Looking at the services running the IP is owned by k8s-dns:
%% kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o wide | grep dns
kube-system    kube-dns                 ClusterIP      10.128.0.10     <none>         53/UDP,53/TCP      2y27d   k8s-app=kube-dns

What would cause this kind of flaky networking on GKE and how can I resolve it?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

So, I found a resolution, though I am not sure I understand the cause.
I turned on NodeLocalDNS on the cluster.
gcloud container clusters update <cluster> --update-addons=NodeLocalDNS=ENABLED

I then checked and saw that node-local-dns was not running.
% kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide | grep node-local-dns

So I trigged a node upgrade for the cluster to cause it to rebuild all the nodes.
That seemed to have fixed it, but I am not sure why. But at least it is working again.
